# Best way to get a constructor function for its namespaced, string representation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have a sting such as `"AppNamespace.SomeObject.ClassName"` and I know that the string represents and actual constructor function, what is the best/recommend way of getting that to use in a statement like `var foo = new AppNamespace.SomeObject.ClassName`?

I could do:

```
var s = "AppNamespace.SomeObject.ClassName"
var foo = new (eval(s))
```

or something like:

```
var parts = "AppNamespace.SomeObject.ClassName".split(".")
var foo = new (window[parts[0]][parts[1]][parts[2]])
```

but I'm wondering if there are better solutions that don't involve `eval` or having to split the string and loop through its parts. Does anyone have any ideas? If not, based on the two solutions I've proposed, what are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do...

```
var obj = new ('AppNamespace.SomeObject.ClassName'
                .split('.')
                .reduce(function(object, key) {
                            return object[key];
                        }, window));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRcPu/).

On older browsers, you could shim [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

This code splits the string by the period (`.`) and then iterates over each from left to right, starting with `window` as the start object (change it if it isn't) and getting each sub property until it arrives with the far right (`ClassName` in your example).

The `new (...)` instantiates this object.

You could write it as a reusable function...

```
var getObjectByString = function(string, baseObject, delimiter) {
    // Only checks for string primitives, but that's OK for this example.
    if (typeof string !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError('First argument is required and must be a string.');
    }

    baseObject = baseObject || window;
    delimiter = delimiter || '.';

    return string
            .split(delimiter)
            .reduce(function(object, key) {
                      return object[key];
                    }, baseObject));
};
```

Comment: Array#reduce has limited availability in the current browser landscape: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: And for what it's worth, I am using underscore.js in my app

Comment: @PhilipWalton In that case, you can use [`_.reduce()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#reduce).

Answer (score 3):

`eval` is evil. Use the loop option.

The good part about the loop option is that objects are passed by reference. So:

```
function getObjectFromString(str) {
    var parts = str.split("."), curr = window, last = parts.pop(), p;
    while( p = parts.shift()) curr = curr[p];
    return curr[last];
}
```

This function returns the targeted object, which in your example is the constructor you're looking for.

```
var s = "AppNamespace.SomeObject.ClassName";
var foo = new (getObjectFromString(s));
```

Comment: There are good reasons why eval is evil, but converting a string that I know is safe to an object surely isn't one of them, right?